# Large file uploads using FileReader and php

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am currently developing an upload module for very large files (larger than the server will ever allow) with progress and all that stuff. See the code bellow.
It works for text files, images, even doc and pdf files.
It crashes for any other file type.
Anyone has any suggestions?

```
var fr = new FileReader;
chunkSize = 524288;
//chunkSize = window.maxPost;
var chunks = Math.ceil(file.size / chunkSize);
var chunk = 0;
function SendSlice() {
    var start, end;
    start = chunk * chunkSize;
    if (start > file.size) {
        start = end + 1;
    }
    end = start + (chunkSize - 1) >= file.size ? file.size : start + (chunkSize - 1);
    status = chunk == 0 ? "start" : (chunk == chunks ? "end" : "progress");
    if (status == 'start') {
            $("#upload-area").append("<p>Upload started for file " + file.name + "</p>");
    }
    fr.onload = function(e) {
        var sliceData = e.target.result;
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
        url : "uploader.php",
        data : {
            filename : file.name,
            status : status,
            slice : sliceData
        }
        }).success(function(data) {
            if (++chunk <= chunks) {
                SendSlice();
                var progress = (chunk / chunks) * 100;
                $("#progress-text").html(progress.toFixed(2) + "%");
                $("#progress").css({
                    width : progress + "%"
                });
            } else {
                $("#upload-area").append("<p>File " + file.name + " uploaded succesfully. Download file <a target='_blank' href='uploads/" + file.name + "'>here</a></p>");
            }
        });
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(file.slice(start, end));
}
SendSlice();
```

And the php code:

```
 if($_POST['status'] == 'start') {
if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_POST['filename'])) {
    unlink("uploads/" . $_POST['filename']);
}
 }
 $data = explode(",", $_POST['slice']);
 $data = $data[1];
 $data = base64_decode($data);
 file_put_contents("uploads/" . $_POST['filename'], $data, FILE_APPEND);
```

Also, i have tried using readAsBinaryString, but i have not idea how the handle the result in PHP. Please advice

Comment: When you say 'crashes' - what error message are you actually getting?  And, what is a particular file you're using to upload - give an example of the type.  That should help.

Comment: yeah, sorry about that. It does not actually crash. It uploads the file, but when i try to download it, it's corupt. I've tried uploading zip, rar, cab, and even exe files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a shot in the dark, but looking at the file.slice API (http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-slice), it says:

> "The slice method returns a new Blob object with bytes ranging from
>   the optional start parameter upto but not including the optional end
>   parameter, and with a type attribute that is the value of the optional
>   contentType parameter."

However, you subtract 1 from "end" before using it - does that mean you leave out 1 byte at each `chunk` (since the end byte isn't included anyway)?

Also, you do sanitize `$_POST['filename']` before using it - not that someone puts `"../yourscript.php"` in there?

Comment: yup, that was exactly the problem! Thanks

Comment: And yes, i will sanitize it.

Comment: Glad to hear, and glad to help. :)